# Следование элемента при скроле

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пожалуйста помогите реализовать, чтобы при скролинге страницы контейнер был закреплен, а при достижения следующего блока контейнер останавливался.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вам подойдет position: sticky. Вот пример:

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.dummy {
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  background-color: lime;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sticky"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
  <div class="dummy">qwerty</div>
</div>
```